# Why the magnet in a Hall-effect thruster?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, plasma-physics, propulsion

I am reading explanations of how a Hall-effect thruster works.

I keep reading that the cathode emits electrons, which are trapped by the B field to form an electron cloud which accelerates the positive charge.

However, I still don't quite see intuitively why the magnet must be there. Can I think of it as increasing the effective mass of electrons, so that they barely move as the ions are attracted towards them, and so the ions absorb all the energy from the potential difference? If so, how would I calculate this effective mass?

Comment: Can you have Hall effect without a magnetic field?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer 'Why does an ammonia maser use ammonia specifically?' 'Because otherwise they would have named it something else!'
Obviously I am asking why the hall effect or the magnet in particular ends up being the thing that makes it useful...

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't obvious to me :) My bad.